# List all session info

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display all the session information of my asp.net page (aspx) in the page. How can I do that?

The programming language is C#.

Comment: Create an aspx page and iterate over the session object.  That is not intended to be sarcastic, but you shouldn't need code for to figure this one out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all session information"? All variables in the current Session (easy), information about all current sessions (not possible, at least not reliable), something else?

Comment: I want to display all the session information (like session variables) and their respective values in my page.

Comment: what part of this are you having trouble with? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx

Comment: I want to iterate over all session information and list them in my web page

Answer (score 37):

These two methods is working for me, improved and corrected David's answer slightly:

## 1st method

```
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
{
    var crntSession = Session.Keys[i];
    Response.Write(string.Concat(crntSession, "=", Session[crntSession]) + "<br />");
}
```

## 2nd method

```
foreach (var crntSession in Session)
{
    Response.Write(string.Concat(crntSession , "=", Session[crntSession .ToString()]) + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach (string s in Session) {
        Response.Write(string.Concat(s, "=", Session[s]));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Display in listbox ( Adding for personal reference)

```
 int[] array = new int[400];
            for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
            {
                var crntSession = Session.Keys[i];
                lstbx.Items.Add(crntSession + "=" + Session[crntSession] + "<br />");
            }
```