# List all session variables including nested nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am having a terrible time, I know how to do this in 6 other languages, but cannot get this to work

I want to see all session variables in a .NET application, INCLUDING nested nodes

I used the code from here [List all session info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584392/list-all-session-info)

and I am able to get the first level of all session variables using

```
<% 
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
{
    var crntSession = Session.Keys[i];
    Response.Write(string.Concat(crntSession, "=", Session[crntSession]) + "<br />");
}
%>
```

here is a portion of my output

```
Mode=M
TreeRefresh=
AdvUser=TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser
```

How can i iterate through AdvUser and get its values as well?

I have tried this, but it returns an error  CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count'

```
for (int i = 0; i < Session["AdvUser"].Count; i++)
```

I also tried this and got the error

> CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Type' because 'System.Type' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
foreach (var crntSession in Session["AdvUser"].GetType())
```

i just don't know how to get to that nested node's values, it doesnt have to be in C# can be in VB

Comment: So you basically want to enumerate over `N` amount of types in your session and get their properties?

Comment: yes that would be my essential question, and any knowledge as to why my attempts at getting that nested node statically didnt work

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense because the AdvUser appears to be an instance of an TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser class. This class has properties but you cant really loop through them like an array unless you use reflection.

Something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2w5ey1e.aspx

```
MyClass MyObject = new MyClass();
     MemberInfo [] myMemberInfo; 

     // Get the type of the class 'MyClass'.
     Type myType = MyObject.GetType(); 

     // Get the public instance members of the class 'MyClass'. 
     myMemberInfo = myType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);

     Console.WriteLine( "\nThe public instance members of class '{0}' are : \n", myType); 
     for (int i =0 ; i < myMemberInfo.Length ; i++)
     {
        // Display name and type of the member of 'MyClass'.
        Console.WriteLine( "'{0}' is a {1}", myMemberInfo[i].Name, myMemberInfo[i].MemberType);
     }
```

Comment: So i can directly print a node of the session like so (because i know it exists) <%= CType(Session("advUser"), TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser).EntityID %> , so does that still apply your answer, or change it any ?